# Powershell - Remove-ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, active-directory, adgroup

I'm trying to remove the groups from users in other domain.

Example: Me as admin wants to disable an user and remove his groups in other domain.

The problem is I don't know how to use `Remove-ADGroupMember -Server` in `Foreach` loop, if I don't use `Foreach` I can use the `-Server` option.

Error of Remove-ADGroupmember:
[image: Error of Remove-ADGroupmember]

How can I get `-Server` property within `Foreach`?

```
$groups = (Get-Aduser -server ServerY -Identity manusys -Properties MemberOf).memberof

Foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Members manusys -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
}
```

The user account `Manusys` has these groups:

```
CN=NO_CamerasAlertMGR,OU=Ordinary Distribution Lists,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=test,DC=com
CN=NO_CamerasAlertCM,OU=Ordinary Distribution Lists,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=test,DC=com
CN=NO_CamerasReport,OU=Ordinary Distribution Lists,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=test,DC=com
CN=NO_CamerasReport_CM,OU=Ordinary Distribution Lists,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=test,DC=com
CN=NO_CamerasReport_MGR,OU=Ordinary Distribution Lists,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=test,DC=com
```

Comment: Why can't you just add `-server` to your existing command? `Remove-ADGroupMember -server ServerY -identity $group [...]`

Comment: There is no Server Option where use this command in Foreach in Powershell ISE

Comment: The ISE isn't showing it correctly then... you can test this by -- on a new line type `Remove-ADGroupMember -Ser` then press tab.

Comment: You are right, Apologize for my confusion

Comment: No need to apologise, everyone has got stuck with code before! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Server` param is available to use with `Remove-ADGroupMember`, using it within `foreach` doesn't change this.

Don't just rely on the ISE auto-prompts, referring to the documentation ([remove-adgroupmember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/)) will always show you what parameters are available.

The problem you are actually seeing, is that the ISE no longer prompts/shows the commands parameters once you've used one of the [Common Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) (`Confirm` & `ErrorAction` in your code, but there are others)...

You can see this with the command by itself - it will continue to prompt for params:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Members manusys
```

But add a CommonParam, and it will not provide its own params anymore:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Members manusys -Confirm:$false
```

---

So to fix your original issue, add the `Server` param to `Remove-ADGroupMember`:

```
$groups = (Get-Aduser -server ServerY -Identity manusys -Properties MemberOf).memberof

Foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Remove-ADGroupMember -server ServerY -identity $group -Members manusys -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
}
```